# Matrix function identities?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

If $W$ is a continuously differentiable $n×n$ matrix valued function on the rectangle $J×J \subset \mathbf{R^2} $, how can I show that

$W(r,s)W(s,r) = I$

$W(r,s)W(s,t) = W(r,t) $

$ \forall$   $r,s,t \in \mathbf{R} $

I've got these identities to work with;

$ W'(s,t) = A(s)W(s,t) $

$\dot{W}(s,t) = - W(s,t)A(t)$

$W(s,s) = I $

$A$ is a continuous $n×n$  matrix valued function defined on $J \subset \mathbf{R} $

Answer (score 0):

The above identities are generalized differential equations, [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential). The solution for the $W(s,t)$ will be a path ordered exponential. There will be a function like $\Pi(r,s):=T(e^{\int_r^s A(t) dt})$ and it holds $\Pi(s,s) = I$.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was looking at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139287/showing-ax-yay-z-ax-y-for-matrix-valued-function-a-with-following-proper?rq=1 
Could you explain the last line to me, the "always replace" part? Thanks